# How to update HttpSession last Accessed time

Tags: java, spring, session

I'm using spring 4,
I'm trying to update a session last accessed. I'm basically trying to manually ping a session.

I have a session id and I want to retrive the session from the session registry update the the last accessed time field.

In [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) api I cant find a "setLastAccessedTime"

Comment: Possibly an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why do you want to update the last accessed time directly?

Comment: the user is logged in project1, he uses project2 to play a game I want him to continue to be logged in in project1.

Comment: So increase the session expiry time in project1.

Comment: We need the maximum time interval to be constant

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Sessions depend on cookies. If you set up an expiry time on the cookie, even if you increased the last access time on the server side, the browser is going to expire the cookie anyway, and without the cookie, the session will expire.

Comment: Hi Lior! Good question! I also need to kind of 'ping a session manually'. I have a chat client that is connected via WebSocket and sending a message though it does not extend the HttpSession so connection is timing out even though users send messages. If you find solution please post it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287810/websocket-chat-message-does-not-prolong-httpsession/